# Porque esse pedaço de código está dando loop infinito?

Tags: java, loop

Todas as variáveis estão declaradas e o Eclipse não está apontando nenhum erro no código inteiro.

**O que eu preciso fazer:** O usuário só pode escolher entre 1, 2 e 3. Qualquer outro input, inclusive textos (exemplo: *teste*) e outros números (exemplo: *4*) deve acusar erro (por isso o último `JOptionPane`) e retomar o pedaço de código (por isso o `do-while`). Caso o usuário entre com os números 1, 2 ou 3, o `do-while` deve ser quebrado (por isso os `brake`s) e outra pergunta (que segue o mesmo esquema) aparece na tela.

Antes estava dando tudo certinho. Se o usuário entrasse com "4", o programa realmente acusava erro e reiniciava a pergunta. Só que quando o usuário entrava com um texto, o programa fechava. Provavelmente porque o `opção` estava sendo transformado em `int`. Aí pensei em transformar o `opção` em `int` apenas se o usuário já tivesse entrado com as opções permitidas. Mas aí começou a dar loop infinito.

Segue o código ATUAL (com problema):

```
do{
  opção=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, cabeçalho+inícioP1+código+espaço+"está alinhada com quantos objetivos da Estratégia da Empresa?"+digite+opção11+"2 ou mais"+opção12+"Apenas 1"+opção13+"Nenhum", cabeçalho, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if(opção=="1" || opção=="2" || opção=="3"){
          opçãoI=Integer.parseInt(opção);
              if(opçãoI==1){
                  pontos1=pontos1+9;
                    break;
                } else if(opçãoI==2){
                    pontos1=pontos1+6;
                    break;
                } else if(opçãoI==3){
                    pontos1=pontos1+3;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você selecionou uma opção inválida. Clique em \"OK\" para retornar.", erro, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
          }
} while(opçãoI!=1 || opçãoI!=2 || opçãoI!=3);
```

E aqui o código antigo:

```
do{ 
            opção=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Bem-vindo ao Console de Priorização de Ideias da Nova A3 (v.1.0.0).\n\nDigite o Código ou o Nome da Ideia.", "BEM-VINDO", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            código=opção;
            do{
            opção=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, cabeçalho+inícioP1+código+espaço+"está alinhada com quantos objetivos da Estratégia da Empresa?"+digite+opção11+"2 ou mais"+opção12+"Apenas 1"+opção13+"Nenhum", cabeçalho, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            opçãoI=Integer.parseInt(opção);
                if(opçãoI != 0 || opçãoI == 0){
                    if(opçãoI==1){
                        pontos1=pontos1+9;
                        break;
                    } else if(opçãoI==2){
                        pontos1=pontos1+6;
                        break;
                    } else if(opçãoI==3){
                        pontos1=pontos1+3;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você selecionou uma opção inválida. Clique em \"OK\" para retornar.", erro, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você selecionou uma opção inválida. Clique em \"OK\" para retornar.", erro, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } while(opçãoI!=1 || opçãoI!=2 || opçãoI!=3);
```

Comment: Acredito que existam n formas de resolver isso. Uma delas seria verificar o tipo da entrada antes de comparar com int, outra seria inserir um jtextfield restrito a números apenas, ou uma alternativa fácil e eficiente seria utilizar [JRadioButtons](http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2014/05/JRadioButton-Botao-Radio-Opcao-Tutorial-de-Java-GUI.html?m=1) e exibir apenas as opções que o usuário tem pra escolher.

Comment: O loop infinito acontece apenas quando o usuário entra com um texto, certo? Ou qualquer valor de entrada causa tal loop?

Answer (score 1):

Veja bem... analizando a condiçao do loop:

```
valor de opcaoI | opçãoI!=1 || opçãoI!=2 || opçãoI!=3  resultado
     1                false        true         true       true
     2                true         false        true       true
     3                true         true         false      true
     4                true         true         true       true
```

Para quebrar o loop quando opcaoI for 1, 2 ou 3 o correto é && ao invés de ||:

```
valor de opcaoI | opçãoI!=1 && opçãoI!=2 && opçãoI!=3  resultado
     1                false        true         true       false
     2                true         false        true       false
     3                true         true         false      false
     4                true         true         true       true
```

Answer (score 1):

tudo bem?

Cara me parece apenas um pequeno erro de lógica. Tente fazer o que Gustavo sugeriu. Vamos ver o porquê:

Quando você entra no primeiro if, isso significa que o usuário digitou corretamente uma das opções validas, 1, 2 ou 3. Ou seja, no seu while, nós temos duas condições verdadeiras e uma falsa então o loop sempre retornará para o ponto inicial do DO.

Minha sugestão é criar uma variável boolean de controle, para definir ao final do DO que tudo ocorreu bem e que o processo não precisa se repetir. Outra opção é alterar o valor da variável opcaoI para um valor fictício como "-1" e alterar a condição do while substituindo os "||" por "&&".

Exemplo:`

```
do{
boolean controle = true;
  opção=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, cabeçalho+inícioP1+código+espaço+"está alinhada com quantos objetivos da Estratégia da Empresa?"+digite+opção11+"2 ou mais"+opção12+"Apenas 1"+opção13+"Nenhum", cabeçalho, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if(opção=="1" || opção=="2" || opção=="3"){
          opçãoI=Integer.parseInt(opção);
                controle = false;
              if(opçãoI==1){
                  pontos1=pontos1+9;
                } else if(opçãoI==2){
                    pontos1=pontos1+6;
                } else if(opçãoI==3){
                    pontos1=pontos1+3;
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você selecionou uma opção inválida. Clique em \"OK\" para retornar.", erro, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
          }
} while(controle);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Os erros são:

String é referência, se você comparar com == vai retornar falso, a não ser que esteja falando do mesmo objeto. Ex: "1" == "1" retorna falso. "1".equals("1") retorna true

Você não precisa usar "do...while".

Como você colocou "break" dentro dos ifs, você pode fazer um "while(true)" que ele vai sair do loop quando entrar em algum if.

Eu dei uma enxugada no seu código... olha aí.

```
while(true) {
        opção = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                cabeçalho + inícioP1 + código + espaço
                        + "está alinhada com quantos objetivos da Estratégia da Empresa?" + digite + opção11
                        + "2 ou mais" + opção12 + "Apenas 1" + opção13 + "Nenhum",
                cabeçalho, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (opção.equals("1")) {
            pontos1 = pontos1 + 9;
            break;
        } else if (opção.equals("2")) {
            pontos1 = pontos1 + 6;
            break;
        } else if (opção.equals("3")) {
            pontos1 = pontos1 + 3;
            break;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Você selecionou uma opção inválida. Clique em \"OK\" para retornar.", erro,
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

E deixo uma dica. Por favor, não use acentos e ç no nome das variáveis. Isso da um calafrio que sobe pela espinha aqui.

Espero ter ajudado.